# Draw a line on top of div with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` on my page that has a background image specified using the `background-image` property. I'd like to be able to draw a line on top of the background image using HTML/CSS (i.e. Not creating a separate image with the line drawn through the image). Is this possible?

**CSS**

```
#myDiv {
    background-image: url('myimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, by "on top of" I mean on top of in terms of z index, not on the top edge of the image. My apologies for not being clear. What I'm trying to do is draw a red slash line through the image.

Comment: Why don't you use border-top ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to add another HTML element, you can use the `::before`/`::after` pseudo elements:

```
#myDiv {
    background-image: url('myimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position: relative;
}

/* this should draw a red line through the center of the image */
#myDiv:after {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vHuHs/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using border-top? See:

```
#myDiv {
    background-image: url('myimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
}
```

[Also available on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hSGVK/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this (add it to your style):

```
border-top: 20px solid red;
```